# Unknown column 'F_ID' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, join

I get this error on the following query

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN recipient = 5 THEN sender ELSE recipient END AS F_ID,u.username 
FROM friendships f LEFT JOIN users u ON F_ID=u.id 
WHERE 5 IN (f.recipient, f.sender)
```

both columns `recipient` and `sender` are present. Why am I not able to use F_ID in on clause?

Comment: You can't reference aliases in `ON` or `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: Well how am I supposed to realize this join? With a subquery?

Comment: He said "aliases", not "calculated columns".

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Well then how am I supposed to reference the calculated column in the on clause?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Actually I figured it out of your comment >> `ON CASE WHEN recipient = 2 THEN sender ELSE recipient END=u.id` Thanks Alvaro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the table structures to test my code but when you can't use aliases, well, you have to do without them:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN recipient = 5 THEN sender ELSE recipient END AS F_ID, u.username 
FROM friendships f
LEFT JOIN users u ON CASE WHEN recipient = 5 THEN sender ELSE recipient END=u.id 
WHERE 5 IN (f.recipient, f.sender)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `F_ID` is not a column name. It's just an alias name. ON clause only use the column name. Alternatively you can use this query :

```
SELECT F_ID, u.username FROM (
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN recipient = 5 THEN sender ELSE recipient END AS F_ID, sender, recipient
    FROM friendships f
)tmp
LEFT JOIN users u ON F_ID=u.id 
WHERE 5 IN (tmp.recipient, tmp.sender)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is with a subquery. Another way is to make the JOIN condition more complicated:

```
LEFT JOIN users ON u.id = IF(f.recipient = 5, f.sender, f.recipient)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify your query that way, if the `LEFT` is not required:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN recipient = 5 THEN sender ELSE recipient END AS F_ID,u.username 
FROM friendships f, users u 
WHERE (recipient = 5 AND sender = u.id) OR (recipient != 5 AND recipient = u.id)
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN is slightly different: with `LEFT JOIN`, rows of the first table will be selected even if there is no match in the 2nd table (NULL will be displayed instead of value). But that query solve the solution, as it not involves F_ID in the WHERE clause

Comment: You're right, I misread your SQL. I'll remove my bogus comment.